# How can i use GetValues when running Js codes by using Jint?

Tags: javascript, jint, jurassic

My question is primitive. But it is very useful. I Checked [Sebastien Ros](https://stackoverflow.com/users/142772/s%C3%A9bastien-ros-msft) Jint application on [GitHub](https://github.com/sebastienros/jint).

How can I GetValue property multiple times?

`GetValues(x,y,z...)` or `GetValue("x").GetValue("y").GetValue("z")`. because I need x,y,z.. result. not only x value.

I have a project that I have to run js codes but there are lots of if comparisons (Be careful it is not "if-else", there are if-if-if and go on...) I have access to all if statement results. I discovered that There is `GetValue` method. But I can access only one value. When I want to access "y", I have to use `GetValue("y")`. But I want to see "x" value in the same time. Maybe I desire that `GetValues("x","y","z"...)`.

```js
            var square = new Engine()
           .SetValue("x", 3) // define a new variable
           .SetValue("y",4)
           .Execute(" var isok1=false;  var isok2= false; if(3>1) { x * x; isok1=true; } if(2>1) { y * y }").GetValue("y") // execute a statement
           .ToObject() // converts the value to .NET
           ;
            Console.WriteLine(square.ToString());

      var square = new Engine()
           .SetValue("x", 3) // define a new variable
           .SetValue("y",4)
           .Execute(" var isok1=false;  var isok2= false; if(3>1) { x * x; isok1=true; } if(2>1) { y * y }      isok1;").GetCompletionValue() // execute a statement
           .ToObject() // converts the value to .NET
           ;
            Console.WriteLine(square.ToString());
```

I checked [Jurassic on codeplex](http://jurassic.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Accessing%20and%20modifying%20global%20variables&referringTitle=Documentation)

and I used it as below :

```js
   var engine = new Jurassic.ScriptEngine();
            engine.SetGlobalValue("x", 15);
            engine.SetGlobalValue("y", 2);
          
            engine.Execute(@" var isok1=false;  var isok2= false; if(3>1) { x=x * x; isok1=true; } if(2>1) { y= y * y; isok2=true; } ");
            Console.WriteLine(engine.GetGlobalValue<int>("x"));
            Console.WriteLine(engine.GetGlobalValue<int>("y"));
            Console.WriteLine(engine.GetGlobalValue<bool>("isok1"));
            Console.WriteLine(engine.GetGlobalValue<bool>("isok2"));
            Console.ReadKey();
```

QUESTION:

How can I do that inside of the myproject But using Jint instead of Jurassic? I need Jint multiGetValues property...

Comment: do you still need help?

Answer (score 2):

You can return an array from JavaScript:

    `var result = (object[])engine.Execute("[x, y, z]").GetCompletionValue().ToObject();`

or a dynamic object

    `dynamic result = engine.Execute("{x, y, z}").GetCompletionValue().ToObject();
    Console.WriteLine(result.x);`